# Log4net - show time (not date) in console

Tags: log4net

I am using log4net to log to the console, and the %date conversionPattern value is too verbose.
I would like to see just hh:mm:ss - the date is not required cos I know what the date is today.

Current config:

[conversionPattern value="%date %-5level - %message%newline" /]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `date` or `utcdate` to format a date to your specification:

> date
>
> Used to output the date of the logging
>   event in the local time zone. To
>   output the date in universal time use
>   the %utcdate pattern. The date
>   conversion specifier may be followed
>   by a date format specifier enclosed
>   between braces. For example,
>   %date{HH:mm:ss,fff} or %date{dd MMM
>   yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff}. If no date format
>   specifier is given then ISO8601 format
>   is assumed (Iso8601DateFormatter).
>
> The date format specifier admits the
>   same syntax as the time pattern string
>   of the ToString.
>
> For better results it is recommended
>   to use the log4net date formatters.
>   These can be specified using one of
>   the strings "ABSOLUTE", "DATE" and
>   "ISO8601" for specifying
>   AbsoluteTimeDateFormatter,
>   DateTimeDateFormatter and respectively
>   Iso8601DateFormatter. For example,
>   %date{ISO8601} or %date{ABSOLUTE}.
>
> These dedicated date formatters
>   perform significantly better than
>   ToString.
>
> utcdate
>
> Used to output the date of the logging
>   event in universal time. The date
>   conversion specifier may be followed
>   by a date format specifier enclosed
>   between braces. For example,
>   %utcdate{HH:mm:ss,fff} or %utcdate{dd
>   MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff}. If no date
>   format specifier is given then ISO8601
>   format is assumed
>   (Iso8601DateFormatter).
>
> The date format specifier admits the
>   same syntax as the time pattern string
>   of the ToString.
>
> For better results it is recommended
>   to use the log4net date formatters.
>   These can be specified using one of
>   the strings "ABSOLUTE", "DATE" and
>   "ISO8601" for specifying
>   AbsoluteTimeDateFormatter,
>   DateTimeDateFormatter and respectively
>   Iso8601DateFormatter. For example,
>   %utcdate{ISO8601} or
>   %utcdate{ABSOLUTE}.
>
> These dedicated date formatters
>   perform significantly better than
>   ToString.

Source: [log4net PatternLayout documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html).